# 'Specified "type" attribute of "video/mp4" is not supported' with Video.js in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-video, video.js

I am receiving the following error (viewed via Firebug) within Firefox while trying to load a video with `video.js`

`Specified "type" attribute of "video/mp4" is not supported`

`All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.`

The issue is odd due to three reasons:

- It's only popped up recently (and we haven't changed any server files)
- It appears inconsistently (around 1 in 4 page loads)
- If I click "continue" in Firebug to skip the breakpoint, the player loads as expected

What could be causing this issue? The fallback does occur (after clicking "continue") and the mp4 is loaded with the flash player fallback.

Comment: Firefox can't play mp4 on desktop...

Comment: Understand, hence videojs is suppose to fallback to flash instead

Comment: Post relevant source code please.

Comment: @NikolaLukic Why are you commenting and downvoting (the answer below) on a question that is nearly 7 years old? Is Firebug even a thing anymore?

Comment: You give +1 on question. Question is good. In default regime when we just say video.src = "video.ogv" looks like firefox take extension from filename and define type="video/ogv" but we need type="video/ogg" .

Comment: I didn't give +1 on question? The question _was_ good but it seems hardly relevant these days. Any additional answers to a 7 year old question are surely irrelevant as the bug was most likely bound to a particular version of video.js or firebug. It doesn't really matter, I just couldn't understand how such an old question/answer was getting votes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm 99% sure that this is a Firebug issue. All the testing I have done around it would suggest that it only occurs when Firebug is running - for example, I don't receive the error when running Firefox's built in inspector.

Comment: No it's not just setup type="video/ogg" and add another source with "video/mp4" This combination works for all broswers..

Answer (score 0):

I too see that. It only occurs in Firefox, not in Chrome/IE. When load/play are called video.js renders the .mp4 into Flash and it proceeds without problems. My assumption is that those failures are informational - though I'd be happy to get rid of them.

There are many differences in operation of video.js in FF vs Chrome/IE (which are .mp4 capable based on different licensing history).  You can detect the differences with a

```
if (vidPlayer.techName !== 'html5')
```

reliably detects the FF user vs the others.

You might play with pre-defining what's coming for FF with:

```
myPlayer.src({ type: "video/mp4", src: pathToMySource })
```

I haven't explored that usage much yet, but one would hope it would help.